# Anomaly Coefficient of $SU(N)$ [Srednicki]

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

In chapter 70 of his book "Quantum Field Theory" ([PDF-Link](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf) to a free draft) Srednicki defines the anomaly coefficient $A(R)$ for a representation $R$ of the group $SU(N)$ as
$$
A(R)\ d^{abc} \equiv \frac{1}{2} \text{Tr}\left( t_R^a \{t_R^b,t_R^c\} \right),\tag{70.33}
$$
where $d^{abc}$ are the totally symmetric structure constants of $SU(N)$ and $t_R^a$ is the $a$-th generator of $SU(N)$ in the representation $R$. He writes

> We normalize the anomaly coefficient so that it equals one for the smallest complex representation. In particular, for $SU(N)$ with $N \ge 3$, the smallest complex representation is the fundamental, and $A(N) = 1$.

This leads to my question:

1. Why *can* we even normalize anything here, since the symmetric structure constants are defined via $\{t^a,t^b\}=\frac{1}{N}1\!\!1 \delta^{ab}+d^{abc}t^c$?
   *Edit*: Especially when the generator's normalization has already been fixed with the Dynkin index: $\text{Tr}(t^a_Rt^b_R)=T(R)\delta^{ab}$, $T(F)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Additionally, he claims that for the fundamental representation of $SU(3)$, $A(F)=1$, whereas when I do explicit calculations using Mathematica and $t=\frac{1}{2}\lambda$ (Gell-Mann matrices), I get $A(F)=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/221851/the-anticommutator-of-sun-generators/362009#362009).

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you for the link. I see that you wrote the anomaly coefficient with a factor of 2 instead of 1/2 in your answer. This way, $A(F)=1$ as claimed. Where does your definition come from? Is this a typo in Srednicki‘s book?

Comment: I'm not familiar with S's conventions. I taught this course out of Schwarz's book 3 yrs ago. See p12' (green) in [my notes](https://ea6d5eb7-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/ckzachos/Home/qftiiinu2015/LectI.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7cp3_yoP6NsBG6gzveddeNkoiYLKzybldCMlIbfeGqwC4BQ-fTeoZMeJJEzDqoW43ErvMm5HdeVGaheCDi74U86jH0UaDwYVczc0e-UjknZiuNu1CCAGkclvsQrXRPkb5xBPSv8aERLeK1xq-mvBZ7ff24F7eb4bxnchqiUyFGLEeY5PGqve9QhL4PcNGhBrJgj4hK1WOinYRHZA_KQskBXWos2ZtfmJc9F8eGMSZOYS9wHkI84%3D&attredirects=0). It is standard material.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for sharing. I will take a look at Schwarz‘s book!

Comment: Indeed, (70.33) above appears pathological.... probably a typo. Is it in the published book? The 1/2 ***should*** be in front of *A*, not under it. Compare to (19.139) of Schroeder & Peskin, or as I indicated, Schwarz, etc....  The crucial equation in my answer in PSE is the *last* equation above the horizontal line, analyzing the anticommutator: *M* vanishes in the fundamental rep, but need not in other reps... Hell, it is nonvanishing for the triplet (adjoint, real) of SU(2)!!

Comment: It is sufficiently nasty that you might write the author, who maintains a voluminous errata web-page....

Comment: It is, in fact, funny. In the first edition of Schwarz I have, (25.36) is correct, as I suggested; but Matt then copies it  wrong in (30.79)! I assume these people will catch their typos as time goes by. In any case, S&P are right, and so are my notes, p 12', even though i skip the irrelevant traceless in the general representation commutator.

Comment: The key point, which is unfortunately not made explicit, is that we can define $d_R^{abc}$ in every representation $R$, and that **they are all proportional to the $d^{abc}$ of the fundamental representation**.

See [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/362009/269697)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution. Since 
$$
\begin{align}
  A(R) d_R^{abc} &= \tfrac{1}{2}\text{Tr} \left( t^a_R \{ t^b_R,t^c_R \} \right)\\
  &= \tfrac{1}{2}\text{Tr} \left( t^a_R \frac{1}{N}\delta^{bc}1\!\!\!\,1 \right) + \tfrac{1}{2}\text{Tr} \left( t^a_R d_R^{bcd}t_R^d \right)\\
  &= \tfrac{1}{2N}\underbrace{\text{Tr} \left( t^a_R \right)}_{0}\delta^{bc} + \tfrac{1}{2}d_R^{bcd}\text{Tr} \left( t^a_R t_R^d \right)\\
  &= \tfrac{1}{2}d_R^{bcd}\ T(R)\delta^{ad}\\
  &= \tfrac{1}{2}d_R^{bca}\ T(R)\\
  &= \tfrac{1}{2}d_R^{abc}\ T(R)\\
  &\quad\leftrightarrow A(R) = \frac{T(R)}{2} \quad\text{ if }d^{abc}\neq 0.
\end{align}
$$
I suppose Srednicki used the Gell-Mann matrices $\lambda$ instead of $t=\frac{1}{2}\lambda$ as generators, for which the usual normalization is $T(F)_\text{Gell-Mann}=2$ and therefore $A(F)_\text{Gell-Mann}=1$.

[Which is strange, since he wrote $T(F)=\tfrac{1}{2}$ a few pages earlier...]

Comment: Actually there is a subtle problem with your proof. You are implicitly assuming that $d_R^{abc}$ on the LHS and the $d_R^{abc}$ on the second line are the same. (The $d^{abc}$ in your original post applies to the defining representation. A priori, we cannot assume a similar relation exists for an arbitrary representation, or even if it does exist, the $d_R^{abc}$ defined in this way and the $d_R^{abc}$ defined in the first line of your solution are the same.)